# If I update the Monero GUI, do I need reinstall the blockchain?

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, blockchain, update

I'm having trouble seeing the funds in my wallet so I want to update to a newer version. However the 90GB blockchain is quite large and I'm wondering if I need to install the blockchain again or does it just reuse the old one?

Answer (score 2):

You can update the GUI and continue to use the blockchain already downloaded.